# Angular animation scale: How move my under element while scale is reducing the size of the above element?

Tags: angular, angular-animations

I have three cards and i'm trying to apply a enter/leave scale animaton when the second card are show and removed. My problem is that when i remove the second element my third element wait the animation of the second card finish to ocuppy the position of the second card.

This is what i tried:

```
animations: [
trigger(
  'scaleAnimation', [
    transition(':enter', [
      style({transform: 'scale(0)', opacity: 0}),
      animate('500ms', style({transform: 'scale(1)', opacity: 1}))
    ]),
    transition(':leave', [
      style({transform: 'scale(1)', opacity: 1}),
      animate('500ms', style({transform: 'scale(0)', opacity: 0}))
    ])
  ]
)]
```

And in my template:

```
<div class="card">
    The first content
</div>

<div [@scaleAnimation] *ngIf="showSecondCard === true" class="card">
 The second content
  <button type="button" (click)="removeSecondCard()">Remove</button>
</div>

<div class="card">
  The third content
</div>
```

[Stackblitz reprodution](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hr1rie)

How i can make the third element ocuppy the position of the second element while the scale animation of the second element is running?